# Dynamic http post parameter name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm using an API for updating profile, by adding nickname, email, phone or password in request parameters each of them will be updated in database.

I want to pass one of these each time depending on user's choice for example when I want to update Nick name:

```
{
 "nickname": "alifa",
 "device_id": "chrome",
 "device_model": "browser",
 "device_os": "angularJS"
}
```

or for updating email:

```
{
 "email": "info@example.com",
 "device_id": "chrome",
 "device_model": "browser",
 "device_os": "angularJS"
}
```

I want to do this by passing property name and property value to a function and it will make an object and send http post request:

```
this.updateDetails = function(dataName, dataValue){
  Loader.global.show();
  var data = $.param({
    device_id: app.device_id,
    device_os: app.device_os,
    device_model: app.device_model
  });
  data[dataName] = dataValue;
  console.log(data);
  return $http.post(app.baseUrl + 'profile/' , data).success(function(){
    Loader.global.hide();
  }).error(function(){
    Loader.global.hide();
  })
}
```

but what it sends to server is just:

[image: Sent data]

Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the object you pass to param. Adding a property to the string you get out of param is pointless.

```
var data = {
  device_id: app.device_id,
  device_os: app.device_os,
  device_model: app.device_model
};
data[dataName] = dataValue;
var encoded_data = $.param(data);
```